# Hiding the Process Monitor application window

Tags: c#

I am creating a scheduled task to run process monitor at its highest privileges. I have a windows service that executes the scheduled task on start. Thus on start of my service, process monitor.exe will be executed shown in a window. **But I don't want to see the window**. I just want the process monitor.exe to run in the background without displaying any windows.

In AutoIT, there is a command: `Run (Procmon.exe,"",@SW_Hide) @SW_Hide = Hidden Window`

I tried this:

```
foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if(pr.ProcessName == "procmon")
    {
        hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass the /Minimized switch on the command line and procmon will launch minimized to the task bar. Also /AcceptEula will bypass the EULA dialog and /Quiet prevents the filter settings confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to tell the process to show no window in the first place, instead of hiding it afterwards.

When running a program from .net you usually already have a `ProcessStartInfo`. Then just set its `WindowStyle` property to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` and that should take care of it.

I haven't tried this myself, but that's the way you usually do it when calling the WinApi functions directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx

Comment: I just tried this for procmon.exe, works for the main window, but when I invoke the follwoing command:
procmon  /OpenLog D:\abc.PML /SaveApplyFilter /SaveAs D:\abc.csv
It still shows a progress window.
I think this technique works only for the main window

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Window Handle of Process Monitor first and then you need to call [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SW_HIDE` to hide it.

You can use [FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow) to get the Window Handle of the ProcMon window.

Edit:

After looking at your code, I tried at my end and it works with the following code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    public static void HideWindow()
    {
        int SW_HIDE = 0;

        foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (pr.ProcessName.Contains("Procmon"))
            {
                //Int32 hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HideWindow();
    }
```

Most likely, the problem with your code is that you are trying to find an exact match of the process name which isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Procmon has built-in functionality to automatically log at startup, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Nope,I am trying to hide the main application window of procmon and I want it to run in the background without any application window shown.

Comment: If you use the Boot Logging feature no application window needs to be shown at all.